# change terminal appearance according to server

Tags: bash, terminal, colors, console

I have 2 different servers (all running Linux) to which I connect via ssh.

After login all terminal background looks the same. I want to have different color themes or backgrounds for different servers.
For example, if I ssh to "server-1" my terminal background turns Gray and if I login to "server-2"  it turn blue.

How can I achieve this?

Note: I am using "MATE Terminal".

Answer (score 3):

In XTerm, you can use the [control sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) in your .bashrc or such. Like:

`if [ "${-//[!i]/}" = 'i' ]; then 
  case $HOSTNAME in
    server1) echo -e '\e]11;darkgray\a\e]10;black\a' ;;
    server2) echo -e '\e]11;darkblue\a\e]10;gray\a' ;;
  esac
fi`

Other terminal emulators have similar features.

In Putty, you can configure the color directly, not sure if these control sequences from XTerm will work (they didn't in cursory testing, haven't looked at my settings, though).

The reason for checking the shell interactive flag instead of for stdout being a terminal (i.e. exit status of `tty` or `[ -t 1 ]`) is in some cases (e.g. Ansible) a tty may be allocated (`ssh -tt`) even for batch processing, and outputting to stdout in such a circunstance could make the stream not "clean", which may cause trouble (e.g. Ansible).

Note: I tested `[ "${-//[!i]/}" = 'i' ]` for the versions of bash, mksh, zsh and ksh available for Centos 7, and it worked in all of them.

Comment: I tried this in XTerm but it does not work. Is "server1"  output of command hostname ?

Comment: $HOSTNAME is an environment variable. If you can use xterm you could change the file `~/.Xresources` of each server to configure the background color.

Comment: @d.putto: try `echo $HOSTNAME` when logged in each server and replace accordingly. If you just wanna try the color changing sequences, just run the `echo -e ...` commands while in the shell on XTerm.

Comment: as @statox says, if you're willing to run XTerm with different parameters, you can configure the colors for different windows in `~/.Xresources`, or run XTerm with `xterm -bg blue -fg gray`, etc.

Comment: Nitpicking: it should be `echo -ne ...`, as there's no point in printing a newline. More important: it should be enclosed by an `if [ -t 1 ]; then ... fi`, so that non-interactive logins don't print it (otherwise it'll break scp, rsync, ...).

Comment: Mate-terminal is essentially an old gnome-terminal using a ~4 year old (and really buggy) vte widget for emulation. That old vte does not yet support these escape sequences. I recommend to try gnome-terminal or roxterm or any other emulator using a newer (Gtk3-based) vte (preferably at least version 0.36).

Comment: I fixed the snippet to only act when on a terminal, but tested for it with `tty -s`, just to avoid being bash specific (don't really know if `test -t` is available in other shells). Thanks for pointing it out, @egmont.

Comment: Thanks. Another solution I've seen is checking for "i" in $-, meaning bash is interactive. I think all are equally fine.

Comment: Actually, checking for 'i' in $- seems better to me now, as it won't "lie". I started using Ansible, and it forces a tty allocation over ssh, so 'tty' will always return true, and echoing to stdout in this case pollutes the stream and breaks it for Ansible. Checking for 'i' in $- is the recommended solution (per some Ansible bug report I have no reference at hand now). I'm updating the answer.